# How to set cdll search path at build time?

Tags: python, ctypes, library-path

I have a shred library `libcustom.so` in a non standard folder, and a python package where I use `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libcustom.so")`.

How can I set `libcustom.so` path at build time (something similar to rpath) ?

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/custom/lib python3 -c "import mypackage"
```

This works fine, but I don't want to use global `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and I don't want to set library path at run time.

```
python3 -c "import mypackage"
```

Results in an error:

> OSError: libcustum.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Where is *libcustom.so* located relative to *mypackage.py*?

Comment: libcustom.so is in a private prefix with various libraries (including alternate versions of standard libraries, which is why I want to remove the LD_LIBRARY_PATH). The python package must be able to be installed in any virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found (there must be better ones) is to create a python module to encapsulate the dlopen call. It is thus possible to insert an rpath at compilation time to resolve dynamic links at runtime.

```c
/* _custom.c */
#include <Python.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static struct PyModuleDef _custommodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    .m_name = "_custom",
    .m_doc = "Convenience module, libcustom.so wrapper",
    .m_size = -1
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit__custom(void)
{
    PyObject *self = NULL, *ctypes = NULL, *cdll = NULL, *lib = NULL;

    /* We must import the library a first time here to allow the use
       of rpath. Otherwise `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` uses dlopen from
       an internal python module, and the internal module's rpath will
       be used for link resolution instead of our. */
    if (! dlopen("libcustom.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, dlerror());
        return NULL;
    }
    if (! (self = PyModule_Create(&_custommodule))) goto fail;
    if (! (ctypes = PyImport_ImportModule("ctypes"))) goto fail;
    if (! (cdll = PyDict_GetItemString(PyModule_GetDict(ctypes), (char*) "cdll"))) goto fail;
    if (! (lib = PyObject_CallMethod(cdll, "LoadLibrary", "s", "libcustom.so"))) goto fail;
    if (PyModule_AddObject(self, "_lib", lib) < 0) goto fail;

    Py_DECREF(ctypes);
    Py_DECREF(cdll);
    return self;

 fail:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "Internal error");
    Py_XDECREF(self);
    Py_XDECREF(ctypes);
    Py_XDECREF(cdll);
    Py_XDECREF(lib);
    return NULL;
}
```

We then add this extension to the python package:

```py
# setup.py
setup(
    ext_modules=[Extension("mypackage._custom", ["_custom.c"])],
    ...
)
```

Then, when building the package, we can insert the rpath:

```sh
python3 setup.py build_ext --rpath /path/to/custom/lib
python3 setup.py install
```

It only remains to replace `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libcustom.so")` by `importlib.import_module("mypackage._custom")._lib`.

Comment: Note: It would be better to use pybind11 or whatever, but I have several legacy python code packages using ctypes.

Comment: Why writing *mypackage* in *C*? What if the original source code contains several hundreds of lines of ode?

Comment: I have planned a rewrite, pure python or pybind11, but I don't have time until the next version of the project. Currently it works with an LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the bash profile, with problematic side effects. Right now I just want to remove the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with minimal code changes.

Comment: If the *.dll* is external would *PyBind11* solve the loading problem?

Comment: Yes. pybind11 will result in a .so python module linked to libcustom.so, where I can put an rpath at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

You can pass the full *.dll* name to *CDLL* (or *cdll.LoadLibrary*).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import os
import sys
from custom_dll_path import CUSTOM_DLL_PATH


DLL_NAME = "dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def main(*argv):
    if argv:
        dll_name = DLL_NAME
    else:
        dll_name = os.path.join(CUSTOM_DLL_PATH, DLL_NAME)
    print("Attempting to load: {:s}".format(dll_name))
    dll00 = ct.CDLL(dll_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

*setup.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from setuptools import Command, setup


class SetDllPath(Command):
    user_options = [
        ("path=", "p", "Dll path"),
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        self.path = ""

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        with open("custom_dll_path.py", "w") as f:
            f.write("CUSTOM_DLL_PATH = \"{:s}\"\n".format(self.path))


setup(
    name="custom_project",
    cmdclass={
        "set_dll_path": SetDllPath,
    },
    #  Other stuff ...
)
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q070640586]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]> echo "int f() { return 0; }" > dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.c  dll00.so  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python3.9 setup.py set_dll_path -p $(pwd)
> running set_dll_path
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  custom_dll_path.py  dll00.c  dll00.so  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]> cat custom_dll_path.py
> CUSTOM_DLL_PATH = "/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q070640586"
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python3.9 code00.py dummy args to fail
> Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 16 2021, 03:08:02) [GCC 9.3.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Attempting to load: dll00.so
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q070640586/code00.py", line 24, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q070640586/code00.py", line 18, in main
>     dll00 = ct.CDLL(dll_name)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: dll00.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python3.9 code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 16 2021, 03:08:02) [GCC 9.3.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Attempting to load: /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q070640586/dll00.so
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had thought of this solution, but what I don't know how to do is inject the CUSTOM_DLL_PATH during the build (libcustom.so is part of an autotools package, and mypackage.py part of an setuptools package). It would take a configuration step during the build. This would probably be possible by overriding the build command.

Comment: Question (might have missed something): why this path needs to be settled at build time? Why can't it be hardcoded in the source file?

Comment: Because it is unknown. This corresponds to 2 different source packages that can be installed in different places.

Comment: What about with this additional *setup.py* step?